# Parsing from Services

Tags: android, arrays

I tried to parse boolean value true from services but I can't do it,When I make debug I get a error in this side `int lengthJsonArr = jsonMainNode.length();` I need to parsing after sending get_UserName and get_password values I should take boolean value,  code is the below Please Help me

```
    String chck;
     boolean b = false;

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        switch (v.getId()) {

            case R.id.btn_girisyap:

                get_userName = userName.getText().toString();
                Log.i("@User_Control", "" + get_userName);
                get_password = password.getText().toString();
                Log.i("@User_Control", "" + get_password);

               if( (get_userName.equals("") || get_userName == null) && (get_password.equals("") || get_password == null) ){

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Lütfen Kullanıcı adı ve şifrenizi giriniz", 
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }

               else if(get_userName.equals("") || get_userName == null){

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Kullanıcı adı boş", 
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }

               else if(get_password.equals("") || get_password == null){

                     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Şifre boş", 
                     Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                 }

               else{

                try {
                    new Thread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {


                    JSONObject returndata = null;
                    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(
                            "http://78.186.62.169:8210/AnketServis.asmx/UserControl");
                    httppost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
                    JSONObject jsonparameter = new JSONObject();

                    try {

                     jsonparameter.put("UserName", get_userName);
                     jsonparameter.put("Password", get_password);

                        httppost.setEntity(new StringEntity(jsonparameter.toString(),
                                "UTF-8"));
                        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                        String responseString = EntityUtils.toString(entity);

                        Log.i("@User_Control", "" + responseString);

                        // final TextView textViewhdn1 = (TextView)
                        // findViewById(R.id.txthdn1);

                        try {
                            returndata = new JSONObject(responseString);
                            JSONArray jsonMainNode = returndata.optJSONArray("d");
                            int lengthJsonArr = jsonMainNode.length();
                            int sorusayisi = lengthJsonArr;
                            Log.i("Log_jsonAkış", "" + sorusayisi);

                            for (int i = 0; i < sorusayisi; i++) {

                                // if (i == sorusayisi)
                                // break;
                                JSONObject jsonChildNode = jsonMainNode
                                        .getJSONObject(i);

                                try {

                                    if (jsonChildNode.optBoolean("UserControlResult",true)) {

                                        Intent im = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Deneme.class);
                                        startActivity(im);
                                    }

                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                    Log.i("ErrorMessage", "" + e.getMessage());

                                }
                            }

                        } catch (JSONException e) {

                        }

                    } catch (Exception e) {

                    }

                        }
                    }).start();

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                    }

                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What issue?what error? When?? Post your logcat please

Comment: I dont takea error but it doesn't work When I make debugging and I taked in this side error int lengthJsonArr = jsonMainNode.length();  debug processing closed

Comment: When I run in debug mode it goes penultimate catch blok

Comment: asp.net has a built in javascript login.  Why aren't you using it?  You can then do isAuthentacted() in your asp.net webservices?